# How can I log Get/Patch/Post statements being sent from my .NET library project?

Tags: c#, .net, http, dll, httprequest

I'm not sure there is anything wrong with my code, but I have a dll .net 4.8 library file that is hooked up to an ERP system that makes REST calls to a third party web based app that is unix-based. We are troubleshooting an issue regarding a strange error but something else came up where they said they are getting a lot of GET statements from the dll for URLs that require PATCH/POST and those urls (specifically one) doesn't have functionality set up for a GET statement.

Is is possible that the .NET objects are sending underlying HTTP calls?

So basically, I would like to log all of the REST statements that are being sent to verify, if possible, where they are coming from. I've combed my code and there is literally one entry point to this statement and I am sending a PATCH and the resource url doesn't require anything to be sent in the body except an empty string.

So is there a way to log all the HTTP calls going out from my project? See code below for my routine.

```
I've looked up how to log and I mostly get results for web projects, but this is a dll project and I'm not sure if those suggestions will work for this.
```

```
try
                {
                    CVToken curToken = CVGlobalRestCalls.GetToken(Session);
                    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", curToken.Token);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var jSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), string.Format("{0}/readytosend/{1}/complete", Globals.GetRESTURL(Session), JobID));
                    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(string.Empty, Formatting.Indented, jSettings), Encoding.Default, "application/json-patch+json");

                    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                    CVJob cvCompletedJob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CVJob>(CVGlobalRestCalls.GetResponseContent(response));
                    outFile.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoice Group {0} has been pushed to CV", JobID.ToString()));

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format(" {0}", ex.Message));
                }
```

Comment: You have a couple of options. You can use an MVC action filter or you can inject middleware to intercept all requests. Then write to either audit tables or a file logger.

Comment: Can't really use middleware, but let me check out the action filter option. Never used that before.

Comment: Just wrap it around your method and it will fire pre method execution and post method execution.